# Migrate database on LAMP stack & ExpressionEngine

Tags: localhost, expressionengine, lamp

I'm pretty new to development, and having trouble configuring an existing ExpressionEngine site to run locally. Everything runs properly on a remote server. To move it to a local LAMPhp setup, I followed the instructions at http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html using a backup of the site database.

The current state of the local environment is:

- Main page loads properly (localhost/url)
- All links generate properly (localhost/url/...)
- All of these links return 404 errors

I confirmed that the database can be accessed successfully through mysql_connect & mysql_select_db using the same host, user, db, and name that are in my database.php file. I suspect the database is still not quite configured properly, but I can't find any good sources online.

Any advice from the more experienced members here would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure your .htaccess file moved over? It's hidden so sometimes it gets left behind.

Comment: Yup, the .htaccess file is in the directory. Thanks though!